# How to run Integration just when merging to master

Tags: git, go, github, travis-ci, travis-ci-cli

I've Travis CI which is working as expected for Go application

```
language: go
go:

- "1.10.x"

script:

- go get -v -t -d ./...
- go test -v ./...
```

This CI takes about a `60-80 sec` to run.

The CI is triggered in two scenarios

> 1. Submitting to new branch
> 2. Merging to the master

Now I've new file which is called `integration_test.go` which is running integration test which takes about 10 min (deployment etc) 
and I want to run this test **only when merging to the master** (since its more heavy) , and not run when submitting to branches, how it can be done it Travis?

I've tried with

```
on:
    branch: master
    condition: `go test -v integration_test.go`
```

Comment: Have you tried reading the Travis docs on conditional functionality?

Comment: @jonrsharpe - yep I try it without success, see my edit please, do you know what am I missing here ?

Comment: That's just not how conditional stages work; see https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/conditional-builds-stages-jobs

Comment: @jonrsharpe - Ok thanks but How should I tell it run only this test `if: branch = master `go test -v integration_test.go`` ?

Comment: @jonrsharpe - can you provide a reference for my issue  please?

Comment: Please *read the docs I've linked to*, they explain exactly how to run a stage conditionally. If you still have an issue after making an honest attempt to implement that, [edit] to clarify.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I read it , so it should be like this , isnt it ? `if: branch = master go test -v integration_test.go`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're likely looking for here is a 'Conditional job'. Using the example here: 
https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-stages/matrix-expansion/

try:

```
language: go

go:
    - "1.10.x"

script:
    - go get -v -t -d ./...
    - go test -v ./...

jobs:
    include:
        - stage: integration
          if: branch = master
          script: go test -v integration_test.go
```